# Javascript error box

Tags: javascript, character, alert, max

Hi guys I have this script here, which counts the characters and lines, now currently though it still allows lines and characters to go into minus, but I would like it to also put up a warning box so it stops the user from being able to put in more text, could you help me out?

javascript:

```
function textCounter(theField,theCharCounter,theLineCounter,maxChars,maxLines,maxPerLine) {
    var strTemp = "";
    var strLineCounter = 0;
    var strCharCounter = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < theField.value.length; i++)
    {
        var strChar = theField.value.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (strChar == '\n')
        {
            strTemp += strChar;
            strCharCounter = 1;
            strLineCounter += 1;
        }
        else if (strCharCounter == maxPerLine)
        {
            strTemp += '\n' + strChar;
            strCharCounter = 1;
            strLineCounter += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            strTemp += strChar;
            strCharCounter ++;
        }
    }

    theCharCounter.value = maxChars - strTemp.length;
    theLineCounter.value = maxLines - strLineCounter;
}
```

and used in code:

```
<textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="10" wrap="VIRTUAL" onKeyUp="textCounter(theForm.comment,theForm.remChars,remLines,900,30,50);"></textarea>
<br><input name=remChars type=text value="900" size=3 maxlength=3 readonly> characters left
<br><input name=remLines type=text value="30" size=3 maxlength=3 readonly> lines left<br>
```

Report to moder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Add a check to the end of the function:

```
var check = strTemp.length <= maxChars && strLineCounter <= maxLines;
if (!check) alert("Error message here!");
```

2 - Trim the text of the field, so it contains only the needed chars:

```
theField.value = theField.value.sbustring(0, maxChars - 1);
```

3 - Add a return to the end of the function:

```
return check ;
```

4 - And change the event binding to:

```
onKeyUp="return textCounter(theForm.comment,theForm...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it comes up with the error box everytime I add a single character, even when I put in a single character

Comment: Ops... I inversed the check. All you need to do is add a `!` (`NOT`) before the `check` in the if clause. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot that works great although everytime the error box comes up, it still adds one line, so you can keep typing and clicking the error box away to add another line and bug the system, any update on this? otherwise much appreciated

Comment: You can trim the text of the field before return the error. See my updated answer.